# about ocd and schizphrenia problem

Tags: aqidah

Assalamu alaikum brother.I have two questions.I am suffering from ocd and schizophrenia.Kufr thoughts comes into my mind.Due to these thoughts somtimes I  push into kufr in my mind(not verbally) or these thoughts committs me kufr.is it considered as kufr?

Answer (score -1):

Narrated Abu Huraira:

The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "Allah has forgiven my followers the evil thoughts that occur to their minds, as long as such thoughts are not put into action or uttered." And Qatada said, "If someone divorces his wife just in his mind, such an unuttered divorce has no effect.:

It was narrated from Abu Hurairah that:
the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: "Allah has forgiven my nation for what they think of to themselves, so long as they do not act upon it or speak of it."

It was narrated from Abu Hurairah that the:
Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said : "Allah has forgiven my nation for the evil suggestions of their hearts, so long as they do not act upon it or speak of it, and for what they are forced to do." |||| **SEE DOWN TEXT**

***DON'T SPEAK ABOUT YOUR THOUGHTS TO ANYBODY BROTHER***

**FOR MORE WATCH ASSIM-AL-HAKEEM YOUTUBE VIDEO ABOUT KUFR THOUGHTS**